# How to programatically add an event handler on a JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid that's already been initialized. How can I add an event handler to it? I've tried

```
grid.setGridParam({
    onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
        alert("onSelectRow");
    }
});
```

but this doesn't do anything (no error, but no alert on select either).

---

*Update*

Turns out the code above actually works fine - although as @jitter points out the new API syntax is preferred. My problem was that `grid` was referring to the wrong object. For some reason in the gridComplete event handler, `$(this)` does not return a reference to the grid, but `$("#" + this.id)` does.

```
// handles the gridComplete event
gridInitialized = function() {
    var grid = $("#" + this.id); 
    grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { onSelectRow: selectRow });
};
```

Comment: Any feedback to my answer? Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: Any thoughts on why `$(this)` and `$("#" + this.id)` are different? Is there a better, "standard" way to get a reference to the grid in the `gridComplete` event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to do this (+ using the new API syntax) is this. Doesn't need a `.trigger("reloadGrid")`

```
grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
        alert("onSelectRow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the improved syntax - actually it turns out that my code above was fine, but the `grid` variable I was using was referring to the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a trigger to reload the grid, like this:

```
grid.setGridParam({
    onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
        alert("onSelectRow");
    }
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

According to the doc's, it should reload the grid, but it doesn't' happen for me if I create the grid, and a bit later add this function.

If I put this code in an onclick handler for a link, it does trigger a reload of the grid.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like `trigger("reloadGrid")` actually isn't necessary - see my update above. Also if you put this in the `gridComplete` handler - which is where I'm doing this - it will send you into an endless loop.