# jqGrid method setGridParam on event subGridRowExpanded causes error

Tags: jqgrid

I successfully configured a subgrid including the subGridRowExpanded callback in my grid.
This means the callback and config values are valid.

I want to remove the subgrid configuration now in order to add it programmatically.

First step - **set subgrid to true**:

```
jQuery('#s3list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    subGrid: true
});
```

This causes the following error:
**TypeError: this.p.subGridOptions is undefined.**

Second step - **adding required subGridOptions**:

```
jQuery('#s3list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {subGridOptions: {
    reloadOnExpand: false
}});
```

This causes the following error:
**TypeError: b.p.colModel[(((n + x) + C) + H)] is undefined**

Adding my valid callback for subGridRowExpanded has no effect - the error stays the same:

```
jQuery('#s3list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        /* lots of valid code */
    }
});
```

Is it possible at all?

Using jqGrid 4.5.2.

Related issues / questions:
https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/478

1. [jqGrid dynamic event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536229/jqgrid-dynamic-event)
2. [How to programatically add an event handler on a JQGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901486/how-to-programatically-add-an-event-handler-on-a-jqgrid)
3. [How to reload JQuery grid keeping scroll position and collapse elements open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706703/how-to-reload-jquery-grid-keeping-scroll-position-and-collapse-elements-open)
4. [Add an event handler to jqGrid after instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148320/add-an-event-handler-to-jqgrid-after-instantiation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that there are misunderstanding what `subGrid: true` option do. jqGrid add column with the namse `subgrid` if you create grid with the option. Because you can't add new column dynamically in jqGrid **you can't switch on subGrid option in the grid without recreating of it** with respect of `GridUnload` method (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232168/315935)).

The method `setGridParam` is stupid. It just use `$.extend` to extend the internal option of jqGrid (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L2882-L2886)). Usage of the method without taking in consideration the specific of the option can break functionality of the grid.

There are some scenarios when one can create grid with subgrid and *hide* the column with (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439239/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15942850/315935)). You should consider in details whether such approach is acceptable for your requirements.